# How to mock an Object in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, specs2

I'm new with scala. I'm trying to UT method inside my object Category, using Specs2 for UT and Mockito for mock. Why should I mock this? because this method take some data from mongo.
There is my example

```
object Category extends MongoBase[Category]("categories") {
....
def myMethod(str: String): String
....
}
```

I've tried to mock object this way:

```
val mockCategory = mock[Category.type]
mockCategory.myMethod("1") returns "2"
```

But my test failed

```
   Cannot mock/spy class 
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
    at CategoryMockSpec.mock(CategoryMockSpec.scala:14)
    at CategoryMockSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CategoryMockSpec.scala:18)
    at CategoryMockSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CategoryMockSpec.scala:16)
```

**Thanks for any advice**!

Comment: Just make the object implement a trait and then use dependency injection instead of referring to the object directly.

Comment: Can you make some code examples for clearly understanding?

Comment: I've made something like this

`object Category extends  MongoBase[Category]("categories") with MyCategory`  

`class MyNewCategory {
  val service: MyCategory = Category
}`  
`trait MyCategory {
  def test = 42
}`  
And made test:  
`val mockCategory = mock[MyCategory]
val category = new MyNewCategory { override val service = mockCategory }
category.service.test returns 222
category.service.test must beEqualTo(42)`  
This is another failed test cause Category trying to connect with mongo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move all behavior, that you need to test into class or trait level.
You'll be able to mixin different implementation in production code and test code.

For example:

```
trait CategoryApi {
  def importantMethod: Int 
}

class Category extends MongoBase[Category]("categories") with CategoryApi {
  override def importantMethod = { /*go to mongo for real data*/ }
}

class CategoryTest with CategoryApi {
  override def importantMethod = 42
}

// service which uses categories

class SomeService(catApi: CategoryApi) {
  def methodToTest = {
    importantMethod
  }
}

// your test

test() {

val service = new SomeService(CategoryTest())
service.methodToTest == 42 // return 42...


}
```