# Mocking an object in Scala using PowerMock

Tags: scala, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to unit test one of my methods. Inside this method it has a line:

```scala
val dynamicFrame = DynamicFrame(dataFrame, glueContext)
```

The issue is that `DynamicFrame` is an object:

```scala
object DynamicFrame {
   ... methods()
}
```

and I'm trying to use PowerMock to mock the call to `DynamicFrame(dataFrame, glueContext)`. I know that PowerMock can mock [classes](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor), but how can I mock an object? I've seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576272/mocking-scala-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849638/how-to-mock-an-object-in-scala) but it doesn't seem straightforward.

In my test code I've tried

```scala
PowerMockito.whenNew(classOf[DynamicFrame])
  .withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockDynamicFrame)
```

but I get a `NullPointerException` on the line where `DynamicFrame` is created. My guess is that it's because I used syntax for mocking classes but `DynamicFrame` is an object.

Does PowerMock (from Mockito) support this functionality out of the gate? If not how would I go about making my test succeed?